# How to share redux code across react apps

Tags: reactjs, redux

I have multiple apps (independent of each other) which has let's say the `Login` state the same in the redux across the apps. The code for `Login` for both action creators and reducers will be the same. So how can I without copy pasting share the code between the apps?

Comment: import the reducer of that Login in your new app and put the imported code in 
CombineReducer({
newReducer:LoginReducer
})

Comment: Can't import files from outside the project directory

Comment: go through this link once https://redux.js.org/recipes/isolatingsubapps may be you can implement your independent apps as the subapps

Comment: I actually wanted to do for `react-native`; that approach is a bit not smooth

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the solution I came up with for this issue was to use [Lerna](https://github.com/lerna/lerna). With Lerna I created a sub-module which was installed as a package for the main app. There are articles available which mention creating a monorepo with Lerna.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a frequently used functions, you can isolate those functions into a separate package called `core` or something like that.

There are some techniques to resolve dependencies to your common functions. If public package is OK, using npm as normal. If private package is a must, one option is using `resolve` feature of `webpack` to treat a local repository as a node module.

https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/